# Emberjs bindAttr not working with ember version 1.0.0-rc.1

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm using the code from this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EsF4R/3/) to try to do something similar (which uses Ember version 0.9.3). However when I use the code with the newer version of Ember (1.0.0-rc.1) the handlebars bindAttr in the input tag on line 11 doesn't seem to be working.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9HeQG/4/) is a version of the same JSFiddle but using the new Ember version. You can see in the output that already the same functionality is not there.

What changed in the new version of Ember and how can I remedy it?

Here is the html which is the same in both JSFiddles:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
{{view Em.RadioButton title="1" option="1" group="default" valueBinding="App.radio1"}}
{{view Em.RadioButton title="Ohai" option="Words" group="default" valueBinding="App.radio1"}}
{{view Em.RadioButton title="3" option="3" group="default" valueBinding="App.radio1"}}
{{view Em.RadioButton title="Dog" option="Dog" group="default" valueBinding="App.radio1"}}
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="App.radio1"}}
</script>
```

And here is the JS which is the same in both JSFiddles:

```
(function(exports) {
var set = Ember.set, get = Ember.get;
Ember.RadioButton = Ember.View.extend({
title: null,
checked: false,
group: "radio_button",
disabled: false,

classNames: ['ember-radio-button'],

defaultTemplate: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<label><input type="radio" {{ bindAttr  disabled="disabled" name="group" value="option" checked="checked"}} />{{title}}</label>'),

change: function() {
Ember.run.once(this, this._updateElementValue);
},

_updateElementValue: function() {
var input = this.$('input:radio');
set(this, 'value', input.attr('value'));
}
});

})({});

App = Ember.Application.create({
radio1: ""
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/9HeQG/6/)

You need to reference the properties in the template like this, using `view.propertyName`:

```
defaultTemplate: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<label><input type="radio" {{ bindAttr disabled="view.disabled" name="view.group" value="view.option" checked="view.checked"}} />{{view.title}}</label>')
```